# Can I Post large data say 5MB using enctype='multipart/form-data' , If http post max size is set to 10kb

Tags: html, apache, jsp, struts, weblogic

Will multipart/form-data, break the post messages in chunks of 10kb so that i can send it to server.

I need to send large string(5mb) to server. On my apache webserver, http post max size is set to 10kb, I can not post it using post method application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default).

Is there any option to send large textarea String to struts action class, from html textarea form field or I must increase http post max size ?

```
<html:form action="/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br />
    <html:textarea property="comment"></html:textarea>
<br />
<html:submit>
    <bean:message key="label.common.button.submit" />
</html:submit>

</html:form>
```

Comment: I am trying to follow this example, but i need to upload String in the form field and not a file

http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-file-upload-example/

Comment: Can you modify server-side program?

Comment: Yes, everything i can modify except apache configuration !

Comment: I would need to asses impact on many other portals which are using same apache server. So I am not much willing to modify apache.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43272/Uploading-Large-Files-Through-Web-Service  describe a project to send large data to the web server in limited data size. You may be able to find some hints for your problem, I hope.

Comment: @Fumu7 This doesnt help much, that article is about uploading a file. I am able to upload file but not able to send large string like whole article.

Comment: Uploading and send large data are same in the sense of data transporting. The point is make a large data to a set of small data segment, and send them within the limit.